# Facebook permissions for filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

Is there any way we can keep facebook permissions as low as possible because right now when a new user uses filepicker to upload images from his facebook account, it shows 2-3 permissions. I'm assuming that its set up as default. But can we reduce those permissions to just basic info and photos?

Answer (score 2):

The three permissions that Filepicker.io asks for are: 'user_photos', 'offline_access', 'publish_stream'. The user_photos and publish_stream permissions are for fetching and saving files, respectively. The offline_access is necessary so that file links stay active even after the user has left the application. These scopes are each necessary for Filepicker.io to function, so are not configurable.

Comment: So, the permission that asks - "Filepicker.io would like to post privately on your behalf" is basically 'publish_stream' scope? And so it's also required?

Comment: Yes exactly - it is used for saving photos to facebook